# A thin rope 200 inches length is going to be cut into three pieces to form one circle and two equal squares.

Tags: calculus

A thin rope $200$ inches length is going to be cut into $3$ pieces to form $1$ circle and $2$ equal squares. Which of the following represents the 
radius of the circle, if the rope was finally cut in such a way that the total area of the shapes is minimized?

[Answer Choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUEUZ.jpg)

Comment: What do you know so far? Any conjectures?

Comment: Why the rope has to be thin?

Answer (score 1):

Call $r$ the radius of the circle and $s$ the side of the square

$2\pi r+8s=200\to \pi r+4s=100\to s=\dfrac{1}{4} (100-\pi  r)$

The total area of the shapes is $A(r)=\pi r^2+2s^2=\pi r^2+2\left[\dfrac{1}{4} (100-\pi  r)\right]^2$

Consider the derivative $A'(r)=2\pi r +4(-\pi)\left[\dfrac{1}{4}(100-\pi r)\right]$

The minimum is where $A'(r)=0$ and $A''(r)>0$

Solve

$2 r-\dfrac{1}{4} (100-\pi  r)=0$

$r=\dfrac{100}{8+\pi }$ and 
$A''(r)=2 \pi +\dfrac{\pi ^2}{4}>0$

so it is the minimum and the total area is

$A\left(\dfrac{100}{8+\pi }\right)=\dfrac{10000}{8+\pi }$

Answer (score 0):

Say we make a circle of radius $r$ and two squares with sides of length $d$. Since the total length of the rope is $l=200$ inches, the total circumference of the shapes, which is $2\pi r + 4d + 4d$, must equal $l$, so that $d = \frac{l-2\pi r}{8}$. We also know that the total area of the shapes will be $A=\pi r^2 + d^2 + d^2$, which we can write as
\begin{align}
A = \pi r^2 + 2\left(\frac{l-2\pi r}{8}\right)^2 = \pi r^2 + \frac{1}{32}l^2 - \frac{1}{8}\pi r l + \frac{1}{8}\pi^2r^2
\end{align}
We want to pick $r$ (and hence $d$) in such a way that the total area $A$ is minimized. And if $A$ is minimal for some value of $r$, we should have d$A/$d$r=0$ at that value of $r$. Let's see what this entails. We have
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}r} = (2\pi+\frac{1}{4}\pi^2) r - \frac{1}{8}\pi l
\end{align}
so requiring d$A/$d$r=0$ yields $(2\pi+\frac{1}{4}\pi^2) r = \frac{1}{8}\pi l$, so that
\begin{align}
r = \frac{\pi l/8}{\pi(2+\pi/4)} = \frac{l/2}{(8+\pi)} = \frac{100}{(8+\pi)}
\end{align}
is the radius for which the total area of the three shapes is minimal.